# Code Parallel.For works only in Debug mode

Tags: c#, tuples, state, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

This code works correctly only in Debug mode. I can't understand what is wrong.

I've tried to modify the code, but without any progress. I would like add the result of calling the function newRow to hashSet if the first parameter is true.

```
foreach (structNumbers sn in numbers)
//Parallel.ForEach(numbers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, (sn) =>
{
    #region                           
    //for (Int32 v = 0; v < 16; v++)
    Parallel.For<Tuple<Boolean, mpz_t, mpz_t>>(0, 16, 
        ()=> { return new Tuple<Boolean, mpz_t, mpz_t>(false, 0, 0); },
        (v, pls, state) =>
    {

        #region
        Interlocked.Increment(ref countChecked);

        //if (newRow(i, j, v, t, index, sn.n, sn.m, out nMin, out mMin) == true)
        //lock(thisLock)
        Tuple<Boolean, mpz_t, mpz_t> res = newRow(i, j, v / 4, v % 4, index, sn.n, sn.m);
        state = new Tuple<bool, mpz_t, mpz_t>(res.Item1, res.Item2, res.Item3);


        return state;

        #endregion

    },
        state => {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (state.Item1 == true)
                {
                    #region  

                    numbersTemp.Add(new structNumbers(state.Item2, state.Item3));
                    //numbersTemp.Add(new structNumbers(nMin, mMin));
                    //Console.WriteLine("bla");
                    #endregion
                }

            }
        }
    );
    #endregion
}
//);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of error/misbehavior you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. numbersTemp doesn't contains all items. it's all

Comment: In the morning a try again use debug, but now my code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You completely ignore (throwing away) `state` passed to your `body` delegate. In result, you have some random results in the end.

Comment: What do you mean?  Could you show how to change this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to aggregate multiple results from parallel loop, then you can do it like this:

```
object lockObject=new object();
HashSet<TResult> result=new HashSet<TResult>();
Parallel.For(0,16,() => new List<TResult>(),(i,pls,list) => {
    TResult r;
    if(TryGetResult(i,out r)) {
        list.Add(r);
    }
    return list;
},list => {
    lock(lockObject) {
        result.UnionWith(list);
    }
});
```

But if `TryGetResult` represent big work (at least it should be big enough to justify overhead of parallel loop), you can do like this:

```
object lockObject=new object();
HashSet<TResult> result=new HashSet<TResult>();
Parallel.For(0,16,i => {
    TResult r;
    if(TryGetResult(i,out r)) {
        lock(lockObject) {
            result.Add(r);
        }
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
ConcurrentBag<TResult> bag=new ConcurrentBag<TResult>();
Parallel.For(0,16,i => {
    TResult r;
    if(TryGetResult(i,out r)) {
        bag.Add(r);
    }
});
HashSet<TResult> result=new HashSet<TResult>(bag);
```

In my opinion, overload of `Parallel.For` with `TLocal` type parameter more suited, when you have scalar result, which can not be updated without lock:

```
object lockObject=new object();
BigInteger result=BigInteger.Zero;
Parallel.For(0,16,i => {
    BigInteger r=GetBigInteger(i);
    lock(lockObject) {
        result+=r;
    }
});
```

In this code, adding two `BigInteger` can be costly operation and can not be done in parallel, so you better rewrite the code like this:

```
object lockObject=new object();
BigInteger result=BigInteger.Zero;
Parallel.For(0,16,() => BigInteger.Zero,(i,pls,subResult) => {
    return subResult+GetBigInteger(i);
},subResult => {
    lock(lockObject) {
        result+=subResult;
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like call thousand times function factorize numbers with different ranges of numbers. For them  which method will be optimal for performance? Task, Parallel, BackgroundWork, await/async?  Function factorise need > 10 minutes for check each range.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev If you have that much of work, than you can make single unit of work to be big enough to consider overhead of parallel invocation as neglectable. So, in my opinion, it does not really matter what you actually choose. But to note: `Parallel` is based on `Task`; `BackgroundWorker` and `await`/`async` is more about asynchrony then parallelism.

Comment: I can't understand in which case I must use parallel and when async method? How to choose right method? What is a criteria? I have read a lot of documentations, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Assuming that we talk about CPU bound tasks, my opinion is that: async is for when you want to offload task to different thread to keep main thread free, as it more valuable, for example UI thread; parallel is for when you want to take advantage of your multi-core processor to process multiple tasks in the same time. Of course, you can run multiple async tasks in the same time to achieve parallelism, but in that case you should handle splitting work between them yourself, while `Parallel` class do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The way this version of `Parallel.For()` works is that it first splits the input into batches. Then for each batch, initialize the local state using the `localInit` delegate, call the `body` delegate for each number in the batch, passing the last state to it and expecting it to return a new state, and in the end, calling `localFinally` on the final state.

Since you're ignoring the state on input of your `body`, you're adding only the last item from each batch to the result.

PetSerAl's answer shows the possible solutions. Probably the most reasonable one to start with is the simplest one with `lock`. If that turns out to be too slow, look for more complicated solutions, including those using local state.